# ansible error when installing r packages through shell

Tags: r, shell, ansible

I am teaching myself ansible and I have two simple files. I want to install R and some packages on a digital ocean server.

hosts

```
[droplets]
<IP ADRESS>
```

playbook.yml

```
- hosts: droplets
  user: root
  sudo: true
  vars:
    - foo: Hello There Ansible
  tasks:
    - name: install R 
      apt: name=r-base state=installed
    - name: install plyr
      shell: echo "install.packages('plyr', repos=c('http://www.freestatistics.org/cran/'))" | R --no-save
```

I understood from [this question](http://example.net/) that I should not use the `command` option but the `shell` command instead.

I still get this error.

```
$ ansible-playbook -i hosts -k playbook.yml
SSH password:
ERROR: Syntax Error while loading YAML script, playbook.yml
Note: The error may actually appear before this position: line 10, column 1

    - name: install plyr
      shell: echo "install.packages('plyr', repos=c('http://www.freestatistics.org/cran/'))" | R --no-save
^
```

However, if I ssh into the machine, the exact command seems to work fine.

```
root@<IP ADRESS>:~# echo "install.packages('plyr', repos=c('http://www.freestatistics.org/cran/'))" | R --no-save

R version 2.15.1 (2012-06-22) -- "Roasted Marshmallows"
Copyright (C) 2012 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
ISBN 3-900051-07-0
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.

  Natural language support but running in an English locale

R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
Type 'contributors()' for more information and
'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.

Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
Type 'q()' to quit R.

> install.packages('plyr', repos=c('http://www.freestatistics.org/cran/'))
Installing package(s) into ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning: dependency ‘Rcpp’ is not available
trying URL 'http://www.freestatistics.org/cran/src/contrib/plyr_1.8.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 393233 bytes (384 Kb)
opened URL
==================================================
downloaded 384 Kb
```

Can anyone pin point what is wrong with my playbook?

Comment: What ansible version do you run ? Your playbook runs fine here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing looks fine, but `command` is a bit safer in general and you can use `Rscript` to perform the task and avoid echoing & piping:

```
- command: Rscript --vanilla -e "install.packages('plyr', repos=c('http://www.freestatistics.org/cran/'))"
```

If you install [littler](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/littler.html) (which is an `apt-get`-able package) you can then issue a `command` to link it to a generally available location:

```
- apt: name=r-cran-littler state=installed
- command: ln -s /usr/share/doc/littler/examples/install.r /usr/local/bin/install.r
```

then use it to do further pkg installs very succinctly:

```
- command: install.r plyr
```

Comment: not only is `command` "safer" but **shell explicitly does not work with pipes**.

Comment: The Rscript command seems to run without errors but when I ssh into the machine I cannot confirm that ```plyr``` has been installed. This is the output from ansible task ```TASK: [command Rscript --vanilla -e "install.packages('plyr', repos=c('http://www.freestatistics.org/cran/'))"] ***
changed: [37.139.10.170]

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************
37.139.10.170              : ok=3    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0```

Comment: I have also tried your littler installer and I get the same result in the output. ```TASK: [command install.r dplyr,ggplot2,stringr] *******************************
changed: [37.139.10.170]```... any idea what to do about that? it doesnt seem to actually install anything ...